# WIldfly Docker 8.2 version stuck in startup

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

We are migrating our legacy application to Widlfly8.2 docker version.
I am trying to copy sqlserver,mysql and postgres driver under /modules. When I am starting my server it's getting hung. Here is the output of log.

```xml
Starting /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0...
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
16:29:24,256 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
16:29:24,699 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
16:29:24,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
16:29:26,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:29:27,045 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
16:29:27,073 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
```

any thought why it's getting stuck ?

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: That is an older version of WildFly too. If you're using Java 9+ that could be the issue.